# How to pass an element in Crawler each function?

Tags: symfony, web-crawler

I parse my xml with Symfony's Crawler and cannot get how can I pass (other words continue) an element and not to include it into final array?

For example:

```
$node->filterXPath('//ExampleNode')->each(function(Crawler $child, $i) {
    if (! count($child->filterXPath('//ChildNode'))) {
        continue;
    }

    return $child->filterXPath('//ChildNode')->text();
});
```

Comment: why don't you just `return null|false` if the current `//ExampleNode` does not have a child node `//ChildNode` ? ... or just skip adding the text to an Array variable?! something like `if ($nodehasNoChildCondition) { return; } $arrayOfTexts[] = $child->text();` ?

Comment: @nifr because false also will be added to the final array...

Comment: [array_filter($array)](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-filter.php) will strip all `false|null` values. You're welcome ;)

Comment: @nifr I don't like this. It is a workaround. But thanks for this too.

Comment: @nifr thanks for your help. I chose to solve my problem using xpath query. I thought crawler's each function may have such thing as 'continue', but ok.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler::reduce(Closure)`](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Crawler.html#method_reduce)

```
$crawler->reduce(function($result, $item) {
    $childNodes = $item->filterXPath('//ChildNode');

    if ($childNodes->count()) {
        $result[] = $item;
    }
});
```